# Is clf.fit guaranteed to return clf?

Tags: scikit-learn

Many examples and source code spot-check indicate that `Estimator.fit()` operates by side-effect, modifying `self`, and returns `self` for convenience.

Can I rely on that behavior?
IOW, is it ***guaranteed*** that `clf.fit` works by side effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

For original scikit-learn apis you can rely on that. Its mentioned in the [user guide here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#fitting):

> The method should return the object (self). ...

You should check that page out to completely check the behaviour of the library.